# Do relish recipes typically include vinegar?

Tags: fruit, sandwich

I'm designing a sandwich and I want to include a fruit relish as a topping. Are there methods that don't include pickling?

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27730/whats-the-difference-between-chutney-and-relish

Comment: English pickles (not pickled anything, just pickle) are made by cooking the fruit/veg in vinegar. Not sure this constitutes pickling per se.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fruit relishes (including salsas, chutneys, and plain sauces like applesauce) can be made without vinegar.  But they almost always include some extra acid - if not vinegar, then usually citrus juice.

The acidity balances the sweetness of the fruit, and it preserves the color.

So you can make a fruit relish, substitute lemon or lime juice for the vinegar, and use it.  But of course, without a full pickling process, the fruit relish will only have a limited life in the refrigerator.